# build TVOS Example App with React Native using github.com/douglowder/react-native-appletv build errors

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, tvos10

I am new to development, I have followed instructions, downloaded a zip of the dev's project,unzip,cd to folder, ran npm install and npm start

In the example app folders when trying to build in Xcode I get numberous React/RCT{file} file not found and will highlight an invalid import statement such as #import

I have been chasing this issue around github for days, tried numerous fixes such as updating the schemes, making an extra cocopods file that references the libraries functions

Anyone have a solution to this referencing problem?

these kinds of errors 
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13371

Frankly I mightnt even be installing the project folder correctly, I dont know
thanks

Comment: What version of Xcode and what version of React Native are you using?

Comment: it could be a setup error, I cannot even see react native in my node modules, it is installed under libraries, xcode 8.3.1, and I dont know where react native version is, there is not a JSON file in the folder